# Auto Scaling Test in ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I did not auto-scaling my container in ECS. It goes down to the lowest 1 and the highest 3 machines. I want to test the Auto Scaling process, but I do not know how to increase the CPU ratio. Is there an app that can increase the amount of CPU and let me see what's going on? Or how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 3rd party stress-testing tools like npm [Autocannon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autocannon) or [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) to increase CPU load and trigger autoscalling.